# AWS CLI returns "null" when querying a IoT device shadow

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-iot

I have an AWS IoT Thing with a device shadow. I can query the device shadow using:

```
aws iot-data get-thing-shadow --thing-name 1234567 --output=json shadow.json
```

The contents of `shadow.json` file looks something like this:

```
{
  "state": {
    "desired": {
      "welcome": "aws-iot",
      "attribute1": 0
    },
    "reported": {
      "welcome": "aws-iot"
    },
    "delta": {
      "attribute1": 0
    }
  },
  "metadata": {
    "desired": {
      "welcome": {
        "timestamp": 1676620139
      },
      "attribute1": {
        "timestamp": 1676620250
      }
    },
    "reported": {
      "welcome": {
        "timestamp": 1676620139
      }
    }
  },
  "version": 2,
  "timestamp": 1676623598
}
```

But when I try to use the `--query` parameter to filter the results, the return is just `null`:

```
aws iot-data get-thing-shadow --thing-name 1234567 --output=json  --query 'state.desired'  shadow.json
null
```

If I test my filtering query on https://jmespath.org/, the filter seems to work just fine and produces:

```
{
  "welcome": "aws-iot",
  "attribute1": 0
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

AWS CLI version: 2.10.0

Comment: Have you tried with double quotes or without quotes?

Comment: Tried with double quotes and without quotes - still only get the `null` response back

Comment: actually, what you want to achieve won't work since this command stores everything into a file. The --query is useful when the cli returns data. But here nothing is returned..

Comment: That would make sense, I just don't get why this command provides the `--query` option if that is the case?

Comment: I think this is just standard parameter that would apply to all cli command except a few like that one. Not all command expect an output file as a mandatory parameter. Most of them just prints json as output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also curious on this and opened an [issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/7679). The reason you can not query looks because the GetThingShadow API does not return the shadow doc as data.

> I think what you're describing is the expected behavior, as the GetThingShadow API only returns an HTTP 200 response if successful.

Comment: Interesting - so it seems they have CLI flags that are not applicable for this particular command.

Comment: Yes... it is a bit confusing. I saw your comment in the issue thread. Thank you,